# JavaScript json making a call to an API

Tags: javascript, json, api

I want to display latitude and longitude after making a call to the API mentioned in the code. Then I want to pass the latitude an longitude values as arguments to make another API call to display formatted address. But this script gives me an error.

```
function loadJSON(callback) {

  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xobj.open("GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Pune", true);
  xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
      callback(xobj.responseText);
    };
  }
  xobj.send();
}

function init() {
  loadJSON(function(responseText) {
      // Parse JSON string into object
      var myObj = JSON.parse(responseText);

      console.log(myObj.results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast.lat);
      var lat=myObj.results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast.lat;
      var lon=myObj.results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast.lng;
      console.log(myObj.results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast.lng);

      address(lat, lon);

    });
}

init();

function address(lat, log){
    var qstr=lat+","+log
    var link="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+qstr+"&sensor=true";
    console.log(link);


    fetchAddress(function(responseText) {
      // Parse JSON string into object
      var myObj = JSON.parse(responseText);


      var adress=myObj.results[0].formatted_address;
      console.log(adress);




    }, link);

}

function fetchAddress(callback, link) {

  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xobj.open("GET", link, true);
  xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
      callback(xobj.responseText);
    };
  }
  xobj.send();
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? If you state the exact problem you're facing, people can help you narrow down to a solution faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the error is in your link.

Use `var link="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+qstr+"&sensor=true";`

Instead of specifying http or https

Comment: This is not an an error see [RFC3986 Section 4.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-4.2)